# Angular 7 Navigate from component to another

Tags: angular, angular7

[image]
How do I navigate from new-contract component to customer-details component?

I tried following on the new-contract component but it keeps navigating to 404.

```
this.back_url = '/customer/customer-details 
this.router.navigate([this.back_url]);
```

Comment: It depends on the routing module you defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(/customer/customer-details);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `router` to navigate between pages. Import the component in the routing module
and do like this

```
this.router.navigate('customer/customer-details')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are navigating with url string, you must use Router.navigateByUrl function.

```
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/customer/customer-details');
```

Comment: No, There is no point of `must` here you could use `navigate` alone as well, but syntax here was wrong